# Begin stream simple mp4 with ffserver

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, ffserver

I want to stream a mp4 and for this I read about ffserver.
So I search and read ffserver documentations but still cant stream a simple file.
For this I done these:
1-A win 8 and last VLC installed.
2-A Ubuntu 13 with last ffmpeg package.
3-A ffserver.conf file saved to /etc/ and copied from http://ffmpeg.org/sample.html (I just copy text in a new file).
4-Run this command : `ffserver -f /etc/ffconfig.conf` and this is result :

```
avserver version 0.8.13-6:0.8.13-0ubuntu0.13.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Jul 15 2014 13:53:49 with gcc 4.8.1
Tue Feb 10 07:29:07 2015 AVserver started.
```

5-Check http://localhost:8090/stat.html and server status is OK.It shows me 4 stream : test1.mpg,test.asf,stat.html,index.html.
6-Run this command : `ffmpeg -i test.mp4 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm`  and this is result :

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.13-6:0.8.13-0ubuntu0.13.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Jul 15 2014 13:53:49 with gcc 4.8.1
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'big.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isom
    creation_time   : 2015-02-05 20:35:09
  Duration: 00:21:36.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 788 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x404, 677 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-05 17:05:45
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 106 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-05 20:35:12
Incompatible sample format '(null)' for codec 'mp2', auto-selecting format 's16'
    Last message repeated 1 times
Incompatible sample format '(null)' for codec 'libmp3lame', auto-selecting format 's16'
[buffer @ 0x900f0c0] w:720 h:404 pixfmt:yuv420p
[scale @ 0x8ea5080] w:720 h:404 fmt:yuv420p -> w:160 h:128 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
[buffer @ 0x8ea34a0] Invalid pixel format string '-1'
Error opening filters!
```

7-I look at error and I can not find why this happen and where I go wrong!

Until now I read many sample and tutorials about ffserver but most of them is about live streaming but I just want to stream some mp4 files.

**EDIT:**

I installed real ffmpeg like this link : https://askubuntu.com/questions/373322/how-to-replace-avconv-with-the-real-ffmpeg-and-have-it-work-right but same error (Just change ppa to `ppa:mc3man/trusty-media` for last release):

```
pp@ubuntu:~$ ffmpeg -i big.mp4 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
ffmpeg version 0.8.13-6:0.8.13-0ubuntu0.13.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Jul 15 2014 13:53:49 with gcc 4.8.1
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'big.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isom
    creation_time   : 2015-02-05 20:35:09
  Duration: 00:21:36.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 788 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x404, 677 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-05 17:05:45
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 106 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-05 20:35:12
Incompatible sample format '(null)' for codec 'mp2', auto-selecting format 's16'
    Last message repeated 1 times
Incompatible sample format '(null)' for codec 'libmp3lame', auto-selecting format 's16'
[buffer @ 0xa04e0c0] w:720 h:404 pixfmt:yuv420p
[scale @ 0x9ee4080] w:720 h:404 fmt:yuv420p -> w:160 h:128 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
[buffer @ 0x9ee24a0] Invalid pixel format string '-1'
Error opening filters!
```

Can any one give me exact commands that I should run for test?
(I know this is like beginners problem but I read doc and test everything as I can but still no luck)

Comment: As output mentions, you are not running FFmpeg but avconv, as Ubuntu installs avconv instead of FFmpeg. I don't know whether this is causing your issue, though.

Comment: I installed real ffmpeg like this link : http://askubuntu.com/questions/373322/how-to-replace-avconv-with-the-real-ffmpeg-and-have-it-work-right but  same error

Comment: Please show the command-line output from the recent ffmpeg.

Comment: Your second console output is also from the ancient, forked version.

Comment: ! As I said I done this like http://askubuntu.com/questions/373322/how-to-replace-avconv-with-the-real-ffmpeg-and-have-it-work-right and test it 3 time.Do you know a better way to get real ffmpeg?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is mp4 stream able with ffserver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568151/is-mp4-stream-able-with-ffserver)

Answer (score 4):

You can't stream `mp4` vidoes using ffserver because it contains global metadata in the file header, which makes random stream access impossible. You can choose another format like `webm` or use MPEG-2 Transport Streams (Apple's HLS).See https://superuser.com/questions/563591/streaming-mp4-with-ffmpeg

```
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 100000
CustomLog -
<Feed streamwebm.ffm>
  File /tmp/streamwebm.ffm
  FileMaxSize 50M
  ACL allow localhost
  ACL allow 128.199.149.46
  #ACL allow 127.0.0.1
  ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.0.255
</Feed>
<Stream streamwebm>
#in command line run : ffmpeg -i yourvideo.mp4 -c:v libvpx -cpu-used 4 -threads 8    http://localhost:8090/streamwebm.ffm
Feed streamwebm.ffm
Format webm

# Video Settings
VideoFrameRate 30
VideoSize 624x368

# Audio settings
AudioCodec libvorbis
AudioSampleRate 48000
AVOptionAudio flags +global_header

MaxTime 0
AVOptionVideo me_range 16
AVOptionVideo qdiff 4
AVOptionVideo qmin 4
AVOptionVideo qmax 40
#AVOptionVideo good
AVOptionVideo flags +global_header

# Streaming settings
PreRoll 10
StartSendOnKey

Metadata author "author"
Metadata copyright "copyright"
Metadata title "Web app name"
Metadata comment "comment"

</Stream>

#stream for flv format
<Feed streamflv.ffm>
  File /tmp/streamflv.ffm
  FileMaxSize 50M
  ACL allow localhost
  ACL allow 192.168.88.89
  #ACL allow 127.0.0.1
  ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Feed>

<Stream streamflv>
  Feed streamflv.ffm
  Format flv
  #Video Settings

  VideoCodec libx264
  VideoFrameRate 30
  VideoSize 640x360
  VideoBitRate 1000

  # Audio settings
  AudioCodec libfaac
  AudioSampleRate 22050
  AudioChannels 2 #this is creating problem
  AVOptionAudio flags +global_header

  MaxTime 0
  AVOptionVideo me_range 16
  AVOptionVideo qdiff 4
  AVOptionVideo qmin 4
  AVOptionVideo qmax 40
  #AVOptionVideo good
  AVOptionVideo flags +global_header

  # Streaming settings
  PreRoll 10
  StartSendOnKey

</Stream>

<Stream stat.html>
  Format status
  ACL allow localhost
  ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Stream>

# Redirect index.html to the appropriate site

<Redirect index.html>
  URL http://yoururl.com
</Redirect>
```

inside your video tag
     `<video>`
         `<source src="http://localhost:8090/streamwebm">`
`</video>`

you can edit the parameters to suit your needs

Comment: I am confused.In that question there is no answer and I read comments but I cant find out how to do this.Can you edit your answer and explain more or a working demo?

Comment: Thank you!I test it and I should delete HTTP from HTTPPort HTTPBindAddress and delete Metadata because of ffserver said they are unknown and Delete flv stream part because libfaac unknown(Whay?).

Comment: Also I test it and go to `http://localhost:8090/streamwebm` and player will be shown but preview image is from middle of video(it seem video play when I run command but I want every user play his/her video from begining) and also I hit play button but buffering and buffering and buffering and no play.I should say I test it with a healthy mp4 and a new fedora and Ubuntu with last ffmpeg.I missed something?

Comment: Also running in ubuntu said about `Failed to set value ''libvx' for option 'c:v'`. Imust thank you for your help because until now no body else help me in this problem.Thank you.

Comment: I wish I could accept it but about that problems,I still cant stream videos.